How to dynamically set an environment variable in Kubernetes StatefulSet based on pod name and port?
I am working on deploying a StatefulSet in Kubernetes for Cube.js Cube Store workers.
I need to set the CUBESTORE_SERVER_NAME environment variable dynamically based on the pod name and a specific port number.
Below is my current StatefulSet configuration:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: cubestore-worker
spec:
  serviceName: cubestore-worker
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: cubestore-worker
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: cubestore-worker
    spec:
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      containers:
      - name: cubestore
        image: cubejs/cubestore:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9001
        env:
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: CUBESTORE_SERVER_NAME
          value: ${POD_NAME}:9001
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: cubestore-worker-configmap
        volumeMounts:
        - name: cubestore-storage
          mountPath: /cube/data
      volumes:
      - name: cubestore-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: cubestore-pvc-shared

I am trying to set CUBESTORE_SERVER_NAME to be a combination of the pod name and port, like cubestore-worker-0:9001. However, my current approach does not seem to work, and the variable is not being set correctly.
How can I correctly set the CUBESTORE_SERVER_NAME environment variable to include both the pod name and the port dynamically within the StatefulSet?

It is called the "Dependent Environment Variable", and you need to use the previous environment variable with () instead of {}.
you can see all the options available in the official docs:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-interdependent-environment-variables/
